June 20, 2024 the legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) APIs will be discontinued

We’re writing to remind you that starting June 20, 2024 the legacy
Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) APIs will be discontinued. This change
will cause the legacy APIs to return an increased number of error
responses.
The discontinued APIs will be completely shut down by July-August 2024.
What you need to do If you’re still using legacy APIs to send messages
with FCM, and do not expect the migration to the HTTP v1 API to be
completed by June 20, 2024, please submit an extension request with
Firebase Support before then to avoid disruptions in your service.
We’re here to help We understand this change may take some planning,
and we're here to support you during this transition. If you have any
questions or need more information about the specific error codes and
error messages, please review the Firebase FAQs.
Thanks,

Todd on behalf of the Firebase team


Can we use the below library for after June 20? It is working in the future?
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1"))
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'


have you asked those of firebase?

yes, above lib also not working after june20?

If you are a user of the legacy HTTP or XMPP APIs please note that these APIs have been deprecated since 2023-06-20 and you should migrate to the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API (HTTP v1) by July-August 2024.
As the message says, if you need to have an extended period, then you can submit an extension request to Firebase Support before then to avoid disruptions in your service.

how to request for extension, can you please share the link?

Here you can directly address to the Firebase Team.

Hey Kathir. Did my answer/comment help? Can I help you with other information?
